# Why does this SKShader display correctly in Xcode particle editor but not in the app I'm building?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I'm experimenting with using an SKShader attached to an SKEmitterNode.

The shader just creates circles. The particle emitter is based on the firefly particle template in Xcode. I left it as is aside from adding in the shader.

The shader looks how I want it in the Xcode particle editor. I created a simple app based on the spritekit game template.
When I compile and run the app with the shader attached to an SKEmitterNode, the circles compromising the particles are clipped. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the didMove(to view:) from my game scene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    let particlePath = Bundle.main.path(
        forResource: "fireflyparticles", ofType: "sks")

    if particlePath != nil {
        let particleNode =
            NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: particlePath!)
                as! SKEmitterNode




        let circleShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "Circles.fsh")

        particleNode.shader = circleShader

        particleNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY) 

        self.addChild(particleNode)
    }
 }
```

and here is the shader:

```
void main() {
const float radius = 0.5;
vec2 position = v_tex_coord - vec2(0.5,0.5);

if (length(position) > radius) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.0), 0.0);
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), 1.0);
  }
}
```

here's an image of the particle editor on the left, compared to the app on the right:

[image: skemitter vs particle editor]

edit:

it seems like this is only an issue in the Mac app. I created a new app targeting iOS and it looks fine there. So... it works in the particle editor, and on iOS... but not in a MacOS app.

Comment: That doesnt look clipped, it looks like it is a square on the right and a circle on the left

Comment: or it actually looks like it is twice as wide, and half is beyond the bound of the node